# CI server when using DX

Tags: salesforcedx, continuous-integration, ci

I have a managed package. Since converting the code to DX I have struggled to create a continuous integration server. I'm hoping someone can give me some pointers.

We use a GitHub flow for managing tickets. So we have a *dev* branch and every feature or bug fix is branched off of that, worked on, and then eventually merged back into *dev*. We also have an *rc* branch that represents our next release (rc stands for for release candidate). So before a release we'll branch off *dev* to *rc* and then if we have bug fixes etc before or after the release (for hotfixes) they'll get merged into *dev* and cherry-picked into *rc*.

We want a CI server that matches *dev* so that product & business can see what we're working on and QA can have a place for regression testing. Scratch orgs do not suit this need because they're a) too difficult for product/business to create and b) too short lived to be useful for great QA (we need long lived so we can create rich data environments).

We cannot just create a dev org that we push to because of namespace issues. As mentioned, we have a managed package so our code is namespaced and we are prevented from using that namespace anywhere but in our packing org and scratch orgs.

What we've settled on for the time being is using a dev org with a *different* namespace than our package. And our CI tool just does a find & sed to replace all instances of our *package* namespace with our *ci* namespace. This works for now but seems like a hack.

It was suggested to me that our CI tool should just create a package and install it somewhere for CI. That sounds like a great idea because it actually gives a better CI experience as it mimics what our *customers* will end up with! But because we can only have 1 packing org I struggle to see how this is a viable solution. The *dev* branch is constantly changing and we cannot have that break things for our release. Yet if we created a package on every merge into *dev* that's exactly what would happen. I have not found a way to automate *removal* of code from the packing org. So that would mean that if we pushed *dev* to our packing org when we go to create a package off the *rc* branch we'd end up with extra stuff that's either work-in-progress (from *dev*) or even things that we changed our minds on and were deleted from *dev* but made their way to the packing org automatically and will remain there until someone removes them manually (when I say *manual* I realize we can use a destructiveChanges.xml file to use tooling for this but that is still a manual process because afact it's not something we can just generate from a tool based on the current state of our repository).

What is the suggested/standard workflow here?

Comment: Scratch orgs deployment can be automated and populated with data, and persisted for 30 days at a time. Are you sure you should be so quick to dismiss them? You can also write a shell script that can do all the work for the non-technical people to use, which basically amounts to double-clicking an icon and waiting.

Comment: We have scratch orgs being created from our CI (Jenkins) with the package namespace. Ensures junk isn't left behind. Developers sometimes create scratch orgs purely for a first pass of QA as that is easy enough to do. A final QA is done after packaging in the context of a lot more data.

Comment: @sfdcfox we have an object structure consisting of 150 custom objects. we have yet to find a good way to populate with all the data we need. if we could overcome that issue perhaps that would work for us

Comment: @KeithC i def can't leave every build around for long because we can do dozens of builds a day and yet have a v limited number of scratch orgs. that being said, i'm open to using a scratch org for this purpose if we could _fully_ populate with real data. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_test_data_example.htm?search_text=import doesn't work for us due to row limits and the fact that we cannot represent our entire object structure with all necessary data in a single query

Comment: @hackerhasid DX is designed to be modular, so you can work on a feature at a time. And you don't spin up a scratch org for every build. The features are there, but it'll take time for you to convert everything. *Especially* for an AppExchange app, it should be far easier than replicating a full org, like we're trying to do. I think you need to have an honest sit down with a DX expert, have a conversation about your current dev cycle, and see how DX can simplify it.